# C# user control gets loaded 2 times instead of once

Tags: c#

I'm working on a  tray icon application that when pressed opens a form that has a couple of panels and in one of the panels there are user controls that i switch on and off with buttons

```
    Form1 form = new Form1();
    private void Icon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        form.Left = Cursor.Position.X - (form.Width / 2);
        form.Top = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Bottom - form.Height;

        Form fc = Application.OpenForms["Form1"];
        try
        {
            if (fc == null)
            {
                form.Left = Cursor.Position.X - (form.Width / 2);
                form.Top = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Bottom - form.Height;
                form.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                fc.Close();
            }
            form = new Form1();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
```

This is the code for showing and hiding the form

[This is how the application looks so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xfzq7.png)

As u can see in the image the user control part is in the middle of the 2 other panels and i switch the user controls with the buttons in the bottom panel

The application uses a TcpListener that is in one of the user controls, once started it listens on a port constantly, but since the user control is loaded twice i get `Only one usage of each socket address is normally permitted` exception and the TcpListener just stops listening because of this.
I've loaded the user controls to the form from the toolbox and all of them are set to `visible = false` from the properties window, and i show the user control when the form loads in the Form1() function.

This is the code that controls the showing/hiding of user controls and switching the background image of the buttons(color)

```
if (lastbutton != null)
{
      lastbutton.BackgroundImage = idleimages[lastbutton];
      lastcontrol.Visible = false;
      lastcontrol.Enabled = false;
}
lastbutton = mycomputerbtn;
lastbutton.BackgroundImage = activeimages[lastbutton];
lastcontrol = myComputerScreen1;
lastcontrol.Enabled = true;
lastcontrol.Visible = true;
lastcontrol.Focus();
```

I don't know if this should be happening but i set a messagebox in the user control and that message box is shown when i open the form in the visual studio designer

Comment: This is off-topic to your question, but some advice.

" The application uses a TcpListener that is in one of the user controls, once started it listens on a port constantly, "

Is poor practice. Your UI should be entirely seperate from things such as TcpListeners. Some reading on MVC (Model View Controller) or MVVM (Model View ViewModel) or anything about separating out the presentation layer of your application from the server / logic. I don't know the answer why it loads twice, otherwise I would have created an answer instead.

Comment: @RyanTheLeach The tcplistener shouldn't be running constantly, it should run just when the user control is oppened and then it should scan network, but instead when i run application i get messagebox that i set where the tcplistener is started even with enabled=false and visible=false. the tcplistener is in a thread that should start when the user control is shown. Is there any other way i can stop the user control from running in the background. i didn't add this to the question as i thought it wasn't any connection with it, could this cause the exception i'm having?

Comment: The user control initializing itself in the background is what makes it appear on screen fast to the user when they need it. I'm not sure how to do what you ask, but you could instead start the TCP listener when it's opened instead of on initialization. But there isn't really enough of the code example to help with that.

Comment: @RyanTheLeach ok i get what u mean, set the thread to start in the enabled event and that way when the user control is shown the tcp starts, how do i handle this for stoping the tcplistener as i think that will solve the whole question and the exception im having?

Comment: I think the problem is that you are calling `new Form1()` twice. Once outside `Icon_Click` and once inside.